# Appending a list without any pointer or reference

Tags: python, list

I am having some trouble with Python, I know in other languages everything you do is pretty straight forward and very logical. However, in Python, `appending` a `list` with `data` to a new `list` simply **keeps a reference or pointer**, and as a result, any changes made to the original list are apparent in the new list.

I have heard about `copy.copy(list[:])`, but I am not 100% percent sure this would work well.

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
new_list = []
new_list.append(list_1[:])
```

However, if you modify **list_1**, you also modify **new_list**, since they point to the same list.

```
>>> list_1.append(4)

>>> print list_1
[1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> print new_list
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

All of this is really annoying to me. If anyone knows a better way, please tell me.

I want to be able to make changes to the **list_1** and continue to `append` to the **new_list**, so that I populate the **new_list** like this:

```
new_list
[0] >>>
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1] >>>
    [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

And sometimes the first list can also be larger than what claimed by this example.

**Made a test run now:**

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> list_1 = [1,2,3]
>>> new_list = []
>>> new_list.append(list_1[:])
>>> print new_list
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
>>> print(new_list)
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> list_1.append(4)
>>> print(new_list)
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> print(new_list)
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> print(list_1)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Strange. Strange. Strange.

Comment: `new_list.append(list_1[:])` => `new_list = [[1, 2, 3]]`. `[:]` _does_ make a copy, so I don't understand your question. We'd need a [mcve]

Comment: Why didn't you get a nested list for `new_list`? This code works if I understand it correctly

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, and you have a MCV right in this code. See for yourself, in my code example.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list

Comment: as said above, the output of your code doesn't match the code. I saw that without testing, but made a test to make sure. Now I'm sure. It's nonsense. Please post a standalone code snippet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @haxxir411 Jean is right. Your code already works for me as well.

Comment: I agree that Python's data model _can_ be weird, confusing and even annoying when you first encounter it if you have experience with other languages that use the more traditional data model. But after a while you will (hopefully :) ) come to appreciate it. In the mean time, you may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: (cont) For a very brief summary with cute diagrams please see [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)

Comment: Well, the last example shows that `[:]` _does_ make a copy of the list, so what's the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Python any complex object is always represented by its reference. By complex I mean not `bool`, `int`, `float`, `NoneType` and other base data types. This is why, two references may point to one object, and any modification using one reference will lead to the same changes shown throught the other reference:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2]
>>> lst2 = lst
>>> lst.append(3)
>>> lst2
[1, 2, 3]
```

If you want to have two different objects you should clone the first one. It can be done by `copy.copy` or `copy.deepcopy` depending on what you actually need:

```
>>> import copy
>>> lst = [1, 2]
>>> lst2 = copy.copy(lst)
>>> lst.append(3)
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3]
>>> lst2
[1, 2]
```

Comment: What? In Python, even primitive data types like bool, int, float, etc are fully-fledged objects. So when you do `a = 42` you  bind the `int` object with the value of 42 to the name "a"; essentially, "a" is a key associated with a pointer to the `int` object. But I find it's best _not_ to think about Python in terms of pointers, references, etc: try to embrace the Python data model on its own terms.

Comment: @PM2Ring I know that. And my explanation doesn't contradict you. Above I was trying a way how to explain it in simple words. I think, my explanation is quite understandable and may help the author.

Comment: @Fomalhaut 1. the term "reference" has a well defined meaning in other languages, that doesn't match how Python works, and 2/ Python bindings work the same for __all__ types - whether builtin or not, mutable or not, whatever, they are __all__ objects, period.

Comment: This such a non answer.